# Editing embedded lines in a paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a text box in my `.indd` project. Currently there is an embedded
line/stroke, which is not grouped but seems to be a hidden symbol or part of a paragraph setting. I do not know how to select it, or apply a different swatch to it, or delete it for that matter.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your cursor *in* the text and .....

**`Paragraph Panel menu > Paragraph Rules`**

[image]

[image]

Note there are two options in the drop down at the upper left corner of the window -- Rule Above, and Rule Below. It's possible to set one alone or both together.